# Simple C++ program experiences [malloc] RTE in Terminal, but runs fine in XCode

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, malloc, clang

I've been doing my best to love and expand my c++ programming, and really appreciate all the memory management features provided by the language.  Compared to most on StackOverflow, I am probably a novice at best, but compared to the general public, I've got mad skillz.

I like to spend my spare time working problems from Project Euler, but recently I stumbled across a problem when trying to create some fine-grained timing in one of my solutions.

Because the c++ I learned only had timing granularity down to the second, I learned that new c++11 extensions and libc++ would enable me to use the `<chrono>` time library to get milliseconds.  Wow, I was excited...or so I thought.

I do most of my tinkering in Mac OSX 10.8, and I like to keep my programming as simple as possible (write code and makefiles in BBEdit, run make in Terminal).  However, it appears that logic has been broken, as I do not understand how I "broke" the Terminal when upgrading to c++11 extensions...

Here is what I started out with before trying to play with `<chrono>`:

```
52     int main() {
53       const int TARGET = 100000;
54       SieveArray sieve(TARGET);
55       int *primes = sieve.getArray();
56   
57       bool go;
58   
59       for (int ix = 1; ix < TARGET; ++ix)
60         if (isOdd(&ix) && !isPrime(&ix)) {
61           go = lookAt(ix, primes, sieve.getLength());
62           if (!go) {
63             cout << ix << endl;
64             ix = TARGET;
65           }//if !go
66         }//if
67       return 0;
68     }//main()
```

My `SieveArray` class is tested and working, and just creates an array of prime numbers (using the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)) using the passed maximum upper bound.

SieveArray.h:

```
 1     class SieveArray
 2     {
 3     public:
 4       SieveArray(int); //constructor
 5       ~SieveArray(); //destructor
 6       int getIndex(int);   //get nth prime number from array
 7       void makeSieveArray(int); //set internal array to new max value
 8       int *getArray(); //returns pointer to internal data array
 9       int getLength(); //returns array length
10   
11     private:
12       int *data; //stored array pointer for this object
13       int max; //max number for prime
14       int length; //length of array
15     };//class SieveArray
```

SieveArray.cpp:

```
 1     #include "SieveArray.h"
 2 
 3     SieveArray::SieveArray(int n) 
 4     {
 5       //store max value
 6       max = n;
 7   
 8       //initial length = 0
 9       length = 0;
10   
11       //and create Array
12       makeSieveArray(max);
13     }//SieveArray constructor
14 
15     SieveArray::~SieveArray()
16     {
17       delete[] data;
18       data = 0;
19     }//~SieveArray()
20 
21     int* SieveArray::getArray() {
22       return data;
23     }//getArray()
24 
25     int SieveArray::getIndex(int idx) {
26       return data[idx];
27     }//getIdx()
28 
29     int SieveArray::getLength() {
30       return length;
31     }//getLength
32 
33     void SieveArray::makeSieveArray(int size) {
34       bool *ary = new bool[size+1];
35   
36       //first set all values to true
37       for (int ix = 0; ix < size+1; ++ix)
38         ary[ix] = true;
39   
40       //sieve algorithm; afterwards, any n>2 that holds 'true' is a prime number
41       for (int ix = 2; ix <= size/2; ++ix) {
42         if (ary[ix] == true) {
43           int count = 2;
44           for (int jx = count * ix; jx <= size; jx = ++count * ix)
45             ary[jx] = false;
46         }//if
47       }//for
48   
49       //count number of prime numbers generated
50       int count = 0;
51       for (int ix = 2; ix <= size; ++ix)
52         if (ary[ix] == true) ++length;
53   
54       //and store the array
55       if ( data ) {
56         delete[] data;
57       }
58       data = new int[length];
59       int idx = 0;
60       for (int ix = 2; ix <= size; ++ix)
61         if (ary[ix] == true) data[idx++] = ix;
62     
63       //cleanup memory
64       delete[] ary;
65       ary = 0;
66     }//sieveArray
```

The only other method of interest, for troubleshooting purposes, is `lookAt()`:

```
30     bool lookAt(int odd, int *primes, int length) {
31       bool done = false;
32   
33       int ix = 0;
34       while (primes[ix] < odd && ix < length) {
35         int jx = 1;
36         while (2*pow(jx,2) + primes[ix] <= odd) {
37           if (2*pow(jx,2) + primes[ix] == odd) {
38             done = true;
39             //cout << odd << " = " << primes[ix] << " + 2*" << jx << "^2" << endl;
40             break;
41           }
42           ++jx;
43         }//while
44         if (done == true) break;
45         ++ix;
46       }//while
```

At this point, the program came up with a solution just fine, quickly, with the following makefile:

```
objects = euler46.o\
  SieveArray.o

euler46: $(objects)
  g++ -o euler46 $(objects)

.PHONY : clean
clean :
  rm euler46 euler46.o
```

Data from the command line:

```
$ c++ --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix

$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Everything works fine :).  So, like a good programmer, I set out to break things.  Here is my first attempt at adding timing...

```
57     steady_clock::time_point begin = steady_clock::now();
58 
59     for (int ix = 1; ix < TARGET; ++ix)
...
68     steady_clock::time_point end = steady_clock::now();
69     duration<double> elapsed = duration_cast<duration<double>>(end-begin);
70 
71     cout << "processing took " << elapsed.count()*1000 << " ms." << endl;
```

After much research on how to get c++11 and libc++ to work in harmony on OSX, I ended up with the following makefile:

```
CXX := clang++

CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++

objects = euler46.o\
  SieveArray.o

euler46: $(objects)
  g++ -lc++ -o euler46 $(objects)

.PHONY : clean
clean :
  rm euler46 euler46.o
```

The `-lc++` flag was a little harder to find, and its absence originally caused all sorts of linking errors, but I made my way through that snafu, and everything compiled, linked, loaded, and voilá!  I had millisecond granularity in c++.  I felt so proud.

But then, as any logical mind would infer...I may want to do things with millisecond granularity on a pretty regular basis.  Hey!  Why don't I write my own utility class?

To spare too many details, although this "question" is quite long already, here is my `SteadyTimer.h`:

```
 1     #include <iostream>
 2     #include <chrono>
 3 
 4     class SteadyTimer
 5     {
 6     public:
 7       SteadyTimer(); //constructor
 8       long getTimeInMillis();
 9       double getTimeInSeconds();
10       void reset(); //stops timer if running, and restarts "now"
11       void stop(); //stops timer and saves elapsed time
12 
13     private:
14       std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin, end; //start, stop times
15       std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed;
16       std::chrono::milliseconds elapsedInMillis;
17       bool isRunning;
18     };//class SteadyTimer
19     //SteadyTimer.h
```

Wrapping this new utility class into my previous code made things very easy:

```
57     SteadyTimer st;
58 
59     for (int ix = 1; ix < TARGET; ++ix)
...
68     cout << "processing took " << st.getTimeInMillis() << " ms." << endl;
```

And wouldn't you know it, everything compiled and ran splendidly in the Terminal.

Then, as any programmer would, I got greedy.  Why not flush out my new utility class and really show it off?  Why not show the time in seconds as well?  How many decimal places was I losing in `std::chrono::milliseconds`?

```
69     cout << "processing took " << st.getTimeInSeconds() << " s." << endl;
```

This is where my 2-day research project into a tiny little math problem and utility class began.  Actually, the project compiles just fine, with no warnings or complaints.  However, at runtime:

```
$ ./euler46
euler46(5868) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff00000012: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

I had heard of malloc in my original c++ instruction (although we never really used it explicitly).  I didn't understand why malloc was even involved, but I did understand there was an "issue" with a pointer not being allocated "somewhere..." so I started the painstaking process of re-reading and "tightening" my code.  All of those efforts never really produced any real results, and I was never able to avoid this runtime error.

I thought it may have been an issue with my `SteadyTimer` class, but I compiled and ran separate programs (in the Terminal using make, having written them in BBEdit) proving that consecutive calls to `getTimeInMillis()` and `getTimeInSeconds()` worked just fine, without all the gobbly-gook of my original solution (line 59) and the main suspect, `lookAt()`.

So finally, I decided to try to debug the program, but didn't make much progress in OSX's Terminal...so, I ended up creating a project in (sigh) XCode, Version 5.1.1 (5B1008).  Not that I am discounting XCode as a developing environment, it just went against my philosophy of doing everything in the command line and basic text editor(s).

Once I had all the files pulled into my project, I added the libc++ library to the linking section (not sure if that was necessary in XCode).  Project built just fine, and I decided to hit 'Run' just for fun.  To my astonishment, the code that would only generate runtime errors in the Terminal didn't complain at the consecutive calls to `getTimeInMillis()` and `getTimeInSeconds()`, displaying the results of each (lines 68 and 69) clear as day in XCode's terminal window.

```
5*******  //just in case anyone wants to solve the problem
processing took 142 ms.
processing took 0.142338 s.
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

My jaw dropped...I anxiously navigated to my 'built' version of the program buried deeply within ~/Library, and ran it from the Terminal.  But in the Terminal, I just received the same `malloc` error.  Since XCode is not detecting the `malloc_error_break`, I cannot seem to "debug" a working program (according to XCode), and am now officially tapped out.

Most of the other errors I found on StackOverflow involved catching an "actual" `malloc_error_break`, and there were some posts regarding programs that worked on the command line but not in XCode.  I'm sure this is not the first, but I am really confused at this point.

Is there any way to make this malloc go away in the Terminal, so I can keep my simplistic approach to programming, and have c++11 extensions as well?

If anyone's really curious, here is the link to [Problem #46 at Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=46), which I originally solved before muddling with the `<chrono>` library.

Comment: This test is backwards: `while (primes[ix] < odd && ix < length)`  if `ix` is out of bounds, you are accessing `primes[bad_index]`.  You should be testing for `ix < length` first.

Comment: `My SieveArray class is tested and working`  With what was pointed out in the first comment, all bets are off.  Show the code.

Comment: Do you really expect someone to read all this?  Please read [ask]